# Кнопки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

Существует input и 10 кнопок:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="input">
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">9</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">10</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии например на кнопку с семеркой в input выводилось 7, с другими числами аналогично?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');

document.querySelector('.btn-group').addEventListener( 'click', e => {
  if( e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' ) input.value = e.target.innerText;
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" id="input">
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">9</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">10</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как сделать чтобы цифры не менялись одну на другую, а шли последовательно?

Comment: пробуйте `input.value += e.target.innerText;`